# Set Layout visible when a ListView item has focus

Tags: android, android-listview, focus

I have a *ListView* and want to set the focus on the selected item. The *ListView* contains 3 *TextView* per row. I want two *LinearLayout* to be Visible when an item is selected.

I have already tried :

```
mListView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus) {
                    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_btn_manipulation_lv)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_tv_username)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

But it doesn't work. So I tried to add the following code before the *setOnFocusChangeListener* :

```
mListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

It doesn't work too.

So I tried to do that : (it doesn't work too)

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < mListView.getChildCount() ; ++i) {
            TextView tv1 = (TextView) mListView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView tv2 = (TextView) mListView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView tv3 = (TextView) mListView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

            View.OnFocusChangeListener ofcl = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if(hasFocus) {
                        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_btn_manipulation_lv)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_tv_username)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            };

            tv1.setOnFocusChangeListener(ofcl);
            tv2.setOnFocusChangeListener(ofcl);
            tv3.setOnFocusChangeListener(ofcl);
        }
```

So my purpose is to make two *LinearLayout* Visible after clicking on an item.

Do you have any idea ? Thanks